# Specific hover effect for keyframe animation CSS

Tags: css, animation, hover

I do have a set of buttons with animation name "slideIn". The keyframes are:

```
@keyframes slideIn {
            0% {opacity: 0; transform: translate(-200px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; padding-left: 110px; width: 300px; margin-left: -100px;}
        }
```

I also do have a button:hover property:

```
button:hover{
            transform: scale(1.1);
            
        }
```

This works for all buttons, but I want to change the hover effect for the buttons using the slideIn animation specifically. I thought maybe this would work, but it did not:

```
button:hover + @slideIn{
            transform: scale(1.1);
            
        }
```

If this is easier to understand, I got some example code looking something like what I want:

```
@keyframes slideUp {
            0% {opacity: 0; transform: translateY(500px);}
            100% {opacity: 1;}

            .hover {
                transform: scale(1.1);
            }
        }
```

This is my button by the way:

```
<button style="text-align: left; width: 200px; opacity: 0; animation-name: slideIn; animation-duration: 0.3s; animation-fill-mode: forwards; animation-delay: {{$delay}}s;" type="submit" class="apply-anim btn btn-outline-primary shadow" name="dateBtn" value="<?php echo $value_key;?>" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="All {{$value_key}}">{{date('d', strtotime($value_key)) . ". " . $month . " " . date('Y', strtotime($value_key))}}
            <span style="float: right;" class="badge bg-danger shadow">{{$value_value}}</span>
            
            </button>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to copy your snippet. Please erase 3rd language such as `{{..}}` before you write.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> ***UPDATE:***
>
> ```css
> .row:hover{
>            transform: scale(1.1);
>            animation: 1s 1 slideIn;
>        }
> ```

or this maybe useful for you.

> ***Update***:
>
> ```css
> /*css*/
> body.apply-anim button:hover{
>            animation: 1s 1 slideIn;
> }
> ```

```html
<!--html-->
<div class="row">
    <body class="apply-anim">
        <button>Hover Me</button>
    </body>
</div>
```

***UPDATE:***
I append snippet I tested.

```css
@keyframes slideIn {
            0% {opacity: 0; transform: translate(-200px);}
            100% {opacity: 1; padding-left: 110px; width: 300px; margin-left: -100px;}
        }
 * {
    transition: all 1s;
 }
 
button {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #00d7ff;
    color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.row:hover > button{
            transform: scale(1.1);
            animation: 1s 1 slideIn;
        }
/*button:hover{
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    transform: scale(1.1) translate(5%);
}*/
```

```html
<div class="row">
<button>
    Hover Me
    <span style="float: right;" class="badge bg-danger shadow">3</span>
</button>
</div>
```

> ***UPDATE:*** Don't add `:hover` state to button. If it is transated, the hover region shifts cause blinking. Capsulate button with `<div/>` or anything and add hover state to that.

Comment: Hello, thanks for awnsering. I've tried what you wrote, and I cannot get it to work. I set the animation to the button, with animation-fill-mode: forward; if that helps in any way.

Comment: @ImCoding I updated what I tested.
**Note:** You set button width to `200px` and in `animation: 0%` you translated the button to `-200px`. This can cause erasing hover state immediatly you hover the button.
That's why the button blinkering. In my snippet, on the half right region, the button will also be blinkering.
If you want to avoid this, you should avoid using `translate: -200px;` or add extra invisible space for shifting button region.

Comment: Thanks! However, I think you missunderstood my wuestion. I see here that you have an animation when you hover the button. I want multiple hover effects to different buttons, for example increasing in size for one button, and decreasing for another button.

Comment: @ImCoding It's simple, add `transition`. maybe  `transition: all 1s;`. :)

Comment: @ImCoding I see, your target. I think you don't need to use `animation`. I updated snippet. Is that similar to what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, but I want the hover animation to be on all buttons with the slideIn animation applied. Not sure if I have a better way of explaining it, sorry

Comment: @ImCoding Ahaa, I updated what you want :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried again, and it somehow still does not work. If you have not seen yet, I updated my original question and added one more example that could probably explain little better what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @ImCoding I thought last snippet I updated will be satisfied for you, but not. Sorry, can you show me a snippet or jsfiddle what you tested and how is it not wroking?

Comment: I honestly don't think it is possible to do what I'm trying to do. But anyway, thank you for your effort in helping me! :)